# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit and cleanup

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have simple application when I need to stop a background thread using Stop() function before application is closed. The problem is that my Main() function has several exit points (return statements)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
/// some code
return;

// some code
return;

//// etc
}
```

I tried to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` as a single place for clean up but it is never called (at least while there is a background thread). Is there a way to work out some nice way to implement that?

Comment: Why not to refactor you Main function to have only one exit point?

Comment: Are you asking how you can optimize to have a single point of exit, or do you want to be able to kill your process and all its background threads at a given moment?

Comment: It is never called because your thread is still running, keeping the process alive.  That was covered in your previous question.

Comment: This line in SystemEvents.cs/1540 keep our application in wait state UnsafeNativeMethods.MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(0, IntPtr.Zero, 100, NativeMethods.QS_ALLINPUT, NativeMethods.MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE) and there is no event fired before it. So bottom line that you should fix you code to get a single point of return instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap all you code in a separate method and call it from Main():

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  DoSomething();
  TerminateThread(); // Thread.Stop() code goes here
}

static void DoSomething()
{
   /// some code
   return;

   // some code
   return;

   //// etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `return;` calls and call a cleanup routine that also terminated the process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Application.ApplicationExit Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx)

According to MSDN the event:

> Occurs when the application is about to shut down.

Comment: Only if his app is window form application. For a console application this will not work.